# При выводе text.setText(R.string.slovo + " " + intValue); - выводится инт адрес ресурса

Tags: android, android-textview

При выводе `text.setText(R.string.slovo + " " + intValue);`- выводится `int` адрес ресурса.Нужно чтобы выводился `String` из ресурса плюс `intValue`. `intValue` меняется динамически поэтому загонять его в ресурсы смысла нет.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все правильно вы должны образаться к ресурсам черех  `getResources.`
Пример

```
getResources().getString(R.string.slovo )
```

Comment: Всё работает) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: text.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.slovo ) + " " + intValue);

Answer (score 2):

В дополнение к ответу @elik хотелось бы отметить, что Android API предоставляет специальный метод для форматирования ресурсов [Resources.html#getString(int, java.lang.Object...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString(int,%20java.lang.Object...)). В нём есть свои подводные камни, но в целом он работает достаточно просто и делает код чище.

Например,

```
<string name="my_string_to_format">Hello, %s!</string>

text.setText(getString(R.string.my_string_to_format, "world"));
```

Слово `world` будет автоматически подставлено вместо %s. Это особенно важно для локализации, т.к. в различных языках строка/число, которое вы хотите добавить, может находиться в разных частях предложения!

Вы можете добавлять произвольное число параметров к строке. Например,

```
<string name="my_string_to_format">I have %1$d %2$s</string>

text.setText(getString(R.string.my_string_to_format, 10, "frogs"));
```